# SQL Group By and Having error

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I have two tables. one is:

```
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                    | Type        | Null | Key | Default |  
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----+------+ 
| facility_id              | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |  
| facility_name            | varchar(30) |      |     | NULL    |                 
| facility_model           | varchar(25) |      |     | NULL    |                 
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
```

another is:

```
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | 
+--------------------------+-------------+---------+-----+------+ 
| facility_id              | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | 
| facility_serial_number   | varchar(30) |      |     | NULL    |                 
+--------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
```

Different facilities could have same facility_serial_number (which is what we want to find out and fix). I want to get all the info of facilities that its facility_serial_number appears more than once.

I tried to use group by and having:

```
select f1.facility_id, f1.facility_name, f1.facility_model, f2.facility_serial_number
from f1, f2 on f1.facility_id = f2.facility_id
group by f2.facility_serial_number
having count (facility_serial_number) > 2
```

It is wrong. I also tried other ways, but no success. What is the corerct query syntax?

Answer (score 0):

It is not obviously clear what your intension are from your sql, but correct syntac would be something like

```
select  f1.facility_id, 
        f1.facility_name, 
        f1.facility_model, 
        f2.facility_serial_number 
from    f1 INNER JOIN
        f2  on  f1.facility_id = f2.facility_id 
group by    f1.facility_id, 
            f1.facility_name, 
            f1.facility_model, 
            f2.facility_serial_number
having count (facility_serial_number) > 2
```

or

```
select  f2.facility_serial_number 
from    f1 INNER JOIN
        f2  on  f1.facility_id = f2.facility_id 
group by    f2.facility_serial_number
having count (facility_serial_number) > 2
```

But if I understand you correctly you might want to try something like

```
select  f1.facility_id, 
        f1.facility_name, 
        f1.facility_model, 
        f2.facility_serial_number 
from    f1 INNER JOIN
        f2  on  f1.facility_id = f2.facility_id 
WHERE   f2.facility_serial_number IN (
                                        select  f2.facility_serial_number 
                                        from    f1 INNER JOIN
                                                f2  on  f1.facility_id = f2.facility_id 
                                        group by    f2.facility_serial_number
                                        having count (facility_serial_number) > 2
                                    )
```

Comment: The last one gives the correct result. The first give no result.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following [Ref](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

```
SELECT f1.facility_id, f1.facility_name, f1.facility_model, f2.facility_serial_number 
FROM f1 LEFT JOIN f2 on f1.facility_id = f2.facility_id 
GROUP BY f2.facility_serial_number 
HAVING count (f2.facility_serial_number) > 2
```

Comment: Got same error: Column f1.facility_id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either a aggragate function or group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * form f1 from where facility_id in(
select facility_id where f2 group by facility_id
 having count(facility_serial_number) > 2))
```